# Clean installation of a MATLAB library on Windows

Tags: windows, matlab, dll, path, dynamic-library

I would like to create an installer for a library (DLL) that can be use in multiple system including MATLAB.
For MATLAB, I have additional *.m and *.mex files to make the DLL functions easily accessible from it.
I also have an installer that modify the PATH environment variable to make my DLL visible to all potential calling system.

**My problem** is that MATLAB does not make use of the system PATH environment variable. Thus, I am looking for a fix that would allow users of my library to run the installer and have my library accessible from MATLAB "out of the box" (possibly after a restart or session reopen).

I currently see 2 ways to do it which I both do not like :

1. Write a MATLAB script that uses addpath()/savepath() functions. I don't like this because :

   a. MATLAB may not always be installed.
   b. This would mess with the user's MATLAB's own path variable.
   c. Upon installing a new version of my library, I would have to mess even more with the MATLAB's path to delete the path to older library before adding the path to the newer library.
2. Look through the system PATH and search for ...\MATLAB\RXXXXn\bin path to use that to install my *.m and *.mex files in the appropriate folder inside MATLAB. I don't like this because :

   a. It would mess with MATLAB's own installation.
   b. Once again, installation of multiple successive versions of the library may cause some issues (currently multiple version may be installed in separate directory, and the PATH redirects to the last one installed, experts users can modify the PATH according to their needs).

Currently, I am leaning towards option 2, but I am looking for a better, cleaner solution to this installation procedure.

Can anyone give me some MATLAB's expert advice ?

Thanks in advance for your help!